# running `exec` programmatically from a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, singularity-container

I want to execute a command in various images. I use a simple `for` bash loop.

```
for i in `ls *.sif`
do
   singularity exec $i cat /etc/os-release
done
```

I expect the script to print the os-release information for ALL images in that directory. Instead, it prints the information of the first one and it returns the prompt. If I run `fg` command the command in the next image is executed, and so on. For n image, I have to run `fg` command n-1 times.

Interestingly, if I replace the command with `timeout 10 singularity exec $i cat /etc/os-release`, it would continue but it won't run the command inside the container.

Comment: What is `ls` doing in there? It should just be `for i in *.sif`.

Comment: See [why not parse ls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see the commands that are being executed.

Comment: @Barmar I think `exec` exits the shell after its first execution - https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/exec.htm

Comment: @Ruturaj That's the `bash` `exec` command, this is the `exec` option to the `singularity` command.

Comment: @Ruturaj See https://www.sylabs.io/guides/3.2/user-guide/cli/singularity_exec.html

Comment: @Barmar interestingly, if I replace the command with `timeout 2 singularity exec $i cat /etc/os-release`, it would continue, but it won't run the command inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

it just works as expected for me (singularity 3.2.0 on CentOS-7), can you re-try with a clean ~/.bashrc file? or with an empty binded $HOME? or with --no-home flag

```
H=`mktemp -d`
for i in *.sif; do
echo "$i"
singularity exec -H "$H" "$i" cat /etc/os-release
done
```

if with these 3 options your exec works fine, you need to fix your .bashrc file.